# Wrap_content for custom progressbar always produces the same size

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to use progress bar with two images in the background drwable( One is empty and one is full). I am using wrap_content. The problem is that the bar is much smaller than the image (if I use imageview it will be like 3 times). Even Itried to change the size of the image and the progress bar is still of the same size.

I don't want to set the width manually and I would rather go with wrap_content

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbEnergyBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_energy" />
```

Here is the background drawable

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/energy_backing"/>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/energy_full"/>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
style=”?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal”
```

to

```
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
```

Comment: Same thing. No changes